# Sitecore - Read alt property from treelist of images

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am reading a `treelist` of images like this:

```cs
var images = new List<Image>();

MultilistField mlf = context.Item.Fields["Images"];

foreach (var id in mlf.TargetIDs)
{
    var item = (MediaItem)Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(id);
    images.Add(new Image
    {
        Url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item),
        Alt = item.Alt,
        Extension = item.Extension,
    });
}
```

The `Url` and `Extension` is correct, but I get no `Alt` text. I want to read the `Alt` text that is directly on the item in the media library and not in an `ImageField`.

Any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: Your code should work. Check if alt text is set on the proper language version of your media item and if everything is published?

Comment: Ahh, i forgot that media items has versions aswell. Thank you for reminding me. It works now ofcourse

Comment: comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Check if `alt` text is set on the proper language version of your media item. And check if your media items are published.

Remember that media items (as all the other items in Sitecore) may have versions, so check if the correct version is in your web database.